# Bootsrtap.css overlap style.css in custom wordpress theme

Tags: css, responsive

On creating a custom theme i faced one problem http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/landro/ lookwise its not look so good because it not supported style.css By default it shows all its css properties from bootstrap.min.css.

I want theme look good like this html http://templategraphy.com/demo/landro/ what should i do so that theme take all its css properties from style.css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can load first `bootstrap.min.css` and then after your main `style.css`

Comment: thanks bindiya yaa i have done this now its looks good but it makes my theme menus in a disorder form please check my theme again  templategraphy.com/wp-demo/landro and suggest some solutions again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load first `bootstrap.min.css` and then after your main `style.css` and Set `About Us` as `About`, then your issue is solved.